# Set url to level above installation directory Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, yii

I don't know if it is even possible so that's why I put my question here.

We have a webserver running a PHP application build within the Yii-framework and we have also integrated Wordpress into that application.

The root contains the Yii-application and a dir with the wordpress installation. Now I would like to know if it's possible to create a page and have it a url outside it's installation dir.

An example:

domain.com shows the Yii application index
domain.com/blog shows the Wordpress homepage

Now I want to create domain.com/foobar and the page foobar comes from Wordpress.

Is it possible and how?

Kind regards,

Pim

Comment: FYI - you have a very poor answer acceptance rate. Many people look at this to decide if they should provide help. Maybe consider going back through your past questions and accepting those which provided the best answer. This will improve your status on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your server will have been setup with your domain name. I don't know if you are using a hosted service, or a cloud based option, but either way you should be able to tell your web server to load different index.php files based on the URL.

Every single web request comes through your web server. You can tell your web server to load different php files depending on the http request URL.

For example, when you setup your sever with domain.com you would have had to (or in most cases its the default) tell your web server to route all domian.com requests to /public/index.php

Following this logic, if you want to load a different index.php file from a different URL, you just have to set this up in your web server. So domain.com/foobar would point to /some/directory/public/index.php

The way you do this very much depends on your server and if you have some server admin software installed e.g. cPanel.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with domain.com/blog redirecting to the index.php file of Wordpress. As I said in that dir Wordpress is already installed...